# Relation between convergences in $L^{p}$ for probability spaces.

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

I have read that for a probability space $(\Omega,\Sigma,P)$ it is true that $f \in L^{p}(\Omega,\Sigma,P)$ implies $f \in L^{q}(\Omega,\Sigma,P)$ if $p>q$, and hence $L^{2} \subset L^{1}$.

I'm not sure if $\|f\|_{2} \le \|f\|_{1}$ for any measurable $f$. Anyway, given a sequence $(f_{n})_{n}$ of functions (not necesarily in $L^{p}$), if $(f_{n})_{n} \to f$ in the $L^{2}$-norm, does this imply $(f_{n})_{n} \to f$ in the $L^{1}$-norm? Thank you.

Comment: You can show $\Vert g\Vert_1\le  \Vert g\Vert_2$. (Apply C-S to $\int |g|\cdot 1$). So, the answer to your question is "yes".

Comment: @DavidMitra Thank you.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables This is true in general for $r>s$, $L^r$ convergence implies $L^s$ convergence for $r,s\in[1,\infty)$. i imagine the proof is via holder

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, by the Hölder inequality (and because $\mu(\Omega)=1$) we have 
$$
\|f\|_1 = \int_{\Omega} |f(x)|\,d\mu(x) \leq \left(\int_{\Omega}|1|^2\,d\mu(x)\right)^{\frac12}\left(\int_{\Omega}|f(x)|^2\,d\mu\right)^{\frac12} = \|f\|_2.
$$
Then, if $f_n \to f$ in $L^2$ we have $0\leq \|f_n-f\|_1 \leq \|f_n-f\|_2\to 0$, thus $f_n \to f$ in $L^1$.